# logistic regression with tensorflow not working

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

Learning something new here so I'm hoping the community can help. I'm mostly a ruby guy but trying to transition to python so I can tackle Machine learning with tensorflow.  I'm having the most difficult time getting this logistic regression script to work using housing data I collected.

Links to data:
https://storage.googleapis.com/datastorage_machinelearning/first1500.csv

logistic regression script:
https://gist.github.com/Nick-Harvey/404b605423b3c19710eb2a1de6cb5880

Script Output:
https://gist.github.com/Nick-Harvey/3eab9262770bfb690730cad1fbadf9eb

The error is somewhat obvious as it's saying that there are incompatible shapes. This is most likely due to the encoding I'm doing to city names adding additional columns. However, I can't seem to figure out a way to be able to fit the data so I can predict house price by sqft and be able to plot it all. Eventually, I'd like to be able to plot the data so you could compare sqft to price and sort it by the city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** I think you're not doing logistic regression. Logistic regression requires the dependent variable be binary and is estimated by maximum likelihood, such as Fischer scoring. Your error function is average least squares and your dependent variable is numerical. It looks like multiple linear regression to me.

---

I studied your code and was able to train a model. Your code crashed later when you calculated the least square loss. But I'll leave that to you.

Your problem is the dimension of your training data. Your dependent variable `y_train` has shape: `(1176)`.

Try:

> y_train = y_train.reshape((y_train.shape[0], 1))

after

> X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)